# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'python' error after update

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I worked with tf 2.3, after an update  to 2.6 got the following error

> AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'python'

in line:

```
if S.__class__ == tf.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that I found is:

```
import tensorflow.python.framework.ops as tf_ops

...

if S.__class__ == tf_ops.EagerTensor:
```

Comment: You should use `if isinstance(S, tf_ops.EagerTensor)` in any case.

Comment: @AKX thank you, nice to know